# css for all tags of a class

Tags: html, css

How can I specify css for all td tags of a table of a certain class?
I tried this:

```
.myclass td {padding: 1px;}
```

But it doesn't work. The html is:

```
<table class="myclass"><tr><td>foo
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/QJTpb/

Comment: The CSS and HTML is perfectly OK. Can you specify exactly what you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: That's the *actual* HTML? You've got another problem then.

Comment: I have figured out I have some caching problem with the CSS not updating. So I am not losing my mind afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work.  Double check:

- Case (ie: .myclass is not the same as .myClass)
- That the styling is valid for a Table Cell

Here's a working example: http://pastehtml.com/view/b2oxzzdp4.html

Comment: It seems I have some sort of caching problem due to the link to css document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.myclass tr td {padding: 1px;}
```

Although it should work the same.

You may need to add more than `1px` of padding to see a difference.  Perhaps it is working and you cannot see the change.

Comment: unnecessary and overkill

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have used padding: 1px. I just meant in general, I didn't understand how to cascade to sub tags. So if I had a tag setup like:  <a><b><c><b></b></c></b></a> I could not specify style for the inner b through .myclass a b, but I would have to use .myclass a b c b?

Comment: this makes the same effect as .myclass td {padding: 1px;}

Comment: It's not "overkill", it's more specific, so it might work if OP has something else styling the `td`. Honestly, this question doesn't make sense, it already should work.

Comment: @myforwik.  I don't think it is unnecessary and overkill.  This is just a more specific rule.  Sometimes this is necessary to override other styles.  In any event, it - as well as the original you posted - should work fine for this and other style changes.  Again, it may be you're not seeing it because the `1px` is small.  Try changing the background color with this rule to see if it works properly.

Comment: @jason - what DotNet said - it works just fine without the `tr`.  It's kind of like writing: `html body div table.myclass tr td { padding: 1px; }` - it would work, but it's overkill.

Comment: @Dave: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: Exactly my point @Wesley Murch.  Much thanks for the link.

Comment: @Wesley - lol - thanks for the random link, but that doesn't change the fact that it's unnecessary and overkill - per my example in my previous statement - there are many ways that will work, and you can continue increasing the specificity until the cows come home - but it has nothing to do with this question.  ([more on specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902858/order-of-prioritization-when-using-multiple-contradictory-css-files/5902873#5902873))

Comment: @Dave: It just seems to be quite a stretch to call two extra characters "overkill" - Jason's example is probably the shortest sensible way to be *slightly* more specific in this case. Besides, we don't know anything about the rest of the CSS so it's all speculation anyways.

Comment: @Wesley - 3 extra characters actually - and I'm confused as to how you can consider it not 'overkill'.  If you write extra code that does the EXACT same thing (per OP's case) as the shorter code - how is that not both unnecessary and overkill?  It seems like my comment was taken as an insult or something - it wasn't meant that way.  As far as "we don't know anything about the rest of the CSS" - exactly - we have what was given.  And, with the given code, adding `tr` is unnecessary (and therefore also overkill).

Comment: I mainly just think this discussion is unnecessary (and therefore also overkill).

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I believe it should work. Check browser console for any errors.
And you can use for table cell padding `table` attribute `cellpadding`

```
<table cellpadding="1">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table.myclass td 
{
padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, you specify CSS for a `<td>` tag of a table of a certain class just like you did it in your question:

```
.myclass td { /* whatever */ }
```

Whether that CSS is what you want is another story.

If you have other items that share that class, and you want to make sure it's a table specifically, you can do this:

```
table.myclass td { /* whatever */ }
```

Comment: @myforkwik - in your example on an answer below: `<a><b><c><b></b></c></b></a>`, `.myclass a b` would refer to both `<b>`s - if you just wanted the inner `<b>`, yes - you'd have to do `.myclass a b c b`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your tags. Other than that, it works.