# In what order does the browser process css?

Tags: css

I have a class that is being styled in 5 different places, what is the order in which the browser goes through each of the different places?

- Inline

  ```
   <div class="yellowtag" style="background: yellow;">This is yellow</div>
  ```
- First processed css file

  ```
  // First instance inside of style.css
  .yellowtag {
      background: yellow;        
  }
  ```
- Second instance of yellow tag in first processed css file

  ```
  // Second instance inside of style.css
  .yellowtag {
      background: yellow;        
  }
  ```
- Second processed css file (below the first .yellowtag rule)

  ```
  // style2.css
  .yellowtag {
      background: yellow;        
  }
  ```
- In the head

  ```
  <head>
       <style>
           .yellowtag {
               background: yellow;        
           }
       </style>
  </head>
  ```

Comment: css is processed in the order it's encountered while parsing the dom. depending on the specific browser implementation, the dom **MIGHT** be modified  as the various files are processed, or it can load all the css, THEN apply the rules. There's a number of rules on what order CSS should be applied: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @MarcB I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: Is there a practical application for this question?

Comment: @cimmanon Yes, there are lots of practical applications for this question, you've never had two files create the same rule? Happens a lot when you're trying to style third party components...

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902858/order-of-prioritization-when-using-multiple-contradictory-css-files In that case, specificity matters (and the order doesn't) , in this case, specificity doesn't matter, because it's the same but the order does matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific order in which the browser processes CSS is:

1: Inline -then-

2: Style Tags -then-

3: 1st CSS File defined in HTML (From top to bottom) -then-

4: 2nd CSS File defined in HTML -And so on-

So if you had a tag in all four the one applied would be the Inline style

Yet all this can be overridden by using !important when defining the property

Answer (score 2):

Since they all have the same specificity (single class name, .yellowtag), the last one in the source code would be the one that would apply.

However, you have an inline style `style="background: yellow;"`, inline styles override other rules and specificity doesn't apply

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity

Comment: No. I think the first one would apply, since inline style always overwrites everything else.

Comment: @Renan Thanks, I did miss the inline style there...

Comment: I see your edit and now I agree with the answer. +1